# reentrant function read()

Tags: c, linux, networking

I have found a server by `select()`, which I want to receive from some clients.

But I find that the server will get blocked in `read()` by gdb.

So I thought of solving it by adding a `SIGALRM`, but 
when a timeout occurs, it's still blocked in `read()`.

This happens because, system calls are automatically restarted, the `read()` 
is not interrupted when the SIGALRM signal handler returns.

Is this  interpretation correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual solution to this problem is to use `SOCK_NONBLOCK` to `socket(2)` or `O_NONBLOCK` to `fcntl(2)`'s `F_SETFL` command. Once the socket is marked non-blocking, it'll never block when you try to read from it, and you won't need to try to straddle the divide between blocking or non-blocking. Are you sure `select(2)` set the filedescriptor? The `select(2)` manpage does describe one reason why you see what you're seeing, but it doesn't seem likely:

> Under Linux, `select()` may report a socket file descriptor as
>   "ready for reading", while nevertheless a subsequent read
>   blocks.  This could for example happen when data has arrived
>   but upon examination has wrong checksum and is discarded.
>   There may be other circumstances in which a file descriptor is
>   spuriously reported as ready.  Thus it may be safer to use
>   `O_NONBLOCK` on sockets that should not block.

If you really just want to prevent the automatic restart, look into `SA_RESTART` in `sigaction(2)` to prevent restartable system calls from restarting.

Comment: and i use select() in this way:  select( FD_SETSIZE, server->fd_readset, 0, 0, timeout ) ,  i use FD_SETSIZE,  this can work? or this will create some mistakes? thank you

Comment: @lxgeek - Don't use FD_SETSIZE there.  It gives you the size of the fd_set which is normally 1024.  The first param of select wants the highest file descriptor + 1.  Keep track of that yourself.  Using FD_SETSIZE forces a search through a thousand FDs you will probably never use.  It will work but it is inefficient.  Also you want to pass "&timeout".